# Jenkins pipeline job with PowerShell step runs indefinitely

Tags: powershell, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-monitoring

I ran into an issue with Jenkins and I can't manage to figure it out. The problem is that, as the title suggest, a pipeline job hangs while a PowerShell is running.

The PowerShell script works with the Az.Monitor module to create alerts for Azure Resources. If I comment this script out, everything works well so I think it's safe to say that it is the problem.
Even so, when I run it in a powershell terminal, it works fine. Even stranger, if I run it in a normal Jenkins job (not a pipeline one), it works fine aswell. I even left the job running overnight.

I saw that someone suggested that maybe some hidden prompts appear while running on Jenkins, but I set the $ConfirmPreference variable to "None" and the issue still happens.

What could be the issue?

Comment: For me, the issue was the Durable-Task Jenkins plugin. I downgraded it from version 1.34 to 1.33 and it worked.

Comment: +1 on Vito Liu-MSFT's comment. @Garbem, I recommend you to consider adding the answer and then accepting it.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT sure, I forgot about this post, I did it now :D. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the issue was the Durable-Task Jenkins plugin. I downgraded it from version 1.34 to 1.33 and it worked.
This plugin was problematic back in 2017-2018 too with the version 1.15.